# Stop back button during data pull?

Tags: windows-phone-7, soap, asynchronous, back-button

Is it possible to stop the back button from working during a data call? For instance, when registering, I don't want someone to press the back button otherwise they may register for my service and not know it (other than confirmation email)? (And the registration will fail the next time they try)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handle the `BackKeyPress` event or override the `OnBackKeyPress` method in your page class, and then set `e.Handled = true;` when you want to prevent backwards navigation.

Note that if you do this, then you should provide the user with a way to cancel your long-running process so they can back out if they want to.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that if you stop the Back button from working your application will fail marketplace submission.

See section [5.2.4 Use of Back Button](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh184840%28v=VS.92%29.aspx).

If a user has the situation where they try to reregister (becuase they don't realise they have registered previously) then you should handle this in your app as the situation may come up anyway.